# not able to vlookup if lookup value is date

Tags: excel, vba

```
   A                A       B
9/24/2017       9/24/2017   10
9/23/2017       9/24/2017   20
9/22/2017       9/23/2017   30
9/21/2017       9/24/2017   40
9/20/2017       9/23/2017   50
9/19/2017       9/24/2017   60
9/18/2017       9/24/2017   70
```

while comparing date value with date it returns formula only,

```
=vlookup(C4,M4:N19,2,FALSE)
```

do we need to change the data format before we lookup?

Comment: What's in range `M4:N19`? You have `A  A B`, what's that?

Comment: A A B is columns names

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure they have the same data format. If the lookup value has a date format the table array has a string format it won't match.